# How to send a text mail with bold unicode characters with python?

Tags: python-3.x, email, utf-8, python-unicode, bold

I want to send a mail with numbers and don't want use html.

But the numbers should be bold. The w3c published the bold characters with [unicode code](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-entity-names/bold.html).

How could I convert numbers e.g. to 1 to **1**?

```
import smtplib

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.header import Header
from email.utils import formataddr, formatdate

bold_map = {0: "U+1D7D7 ", 1: "U+1D7CF", 2: "U+1D7D0", 3: "U+1D7D1", 4: "2U+1D7D2", 5: "U+1D7D3", 6: "U+1D7D4", 7: "U+1D7D5", 8: "U+1D7D6", 9: "U+1D7D7"}

numbers = "0123456789"

bold_numbers = ""
for number in numbers:
    bold_numbers += bold_map[int(number)]

 print(bold_numbers)

 msg = MIMEMultipart()
 msg["subject"] = "Test"

 msg["From"] = formataddr(("Stackoverflow", "test@stackoverflow.com"))
 msg["To"] = "test@stackoverflow.com"

 msg["Date"] = formatdate(localtime=True)

 body = numbers
 msg.attach(MIMEText(body, "plain"))

 msg_str = msg.as_string()

 email = smtplib.SMTP()
 email.connect()
 email.sendmail(sender, receiver, msg_str)
 email.quit()
```

Comment: Do not abuse Unicode. You linked mathematical symbols, so do not expect clients will have mathematical fonts installed or ready to be used. In any case Unicode doesn't support formatting stuffs, formatting should be handled by higher level protocol. Else: good luck broking expectation (and e.g. search functions, alphabetical sorting, etc.)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Excuse me, but I would think that all latest email clients support unicode, or? So why should it be a problem to show bold unicode charaters. Also smileys are unicode.

Comment: There is no "bold Unicode". Bold is considered to be outside Unicode scope (like subscript, superscript, italic). The page you linked clearly mark as mathematical symbols (which are displayed as bold), but the semantic is different. Do not expect many fonts will support mathematical symbols (so maybe few Helvetica like fonts)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Thank you. This wan't clear for me. But Helvetia would be fine for me, or is there bold also excluded? I am also interested for bold characters.

Comment: @ikreb Even so, you simply can't specify a font or any formatting info in plain Unicode text.  You need to use something like HTML or RTF for that purpose. There is simply no getting around that if you intent to send a text-based email. Otherwise, you will have to put your formatted text into a PDF or DOC file instead and then attach it to the email.